# Adding alpha to .dds file

Tags: python, numpy, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, osgeo

how can I add to a .dds file (without alpha), an alpha channel?
The source for the alpha data, is a 8bit gray tiff.
I tried gdal_merge but it seems that adds transparency to the rgb and not a new alpha channel.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a greyscale image into the alpha channel of an image using **ImageMagick**, which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows, like this:

```
magick input.dds greyscale.tif -compose copyopacity -composite result.dds
```

The input images could equally be TIF, GIF, or JPEG and the output image could be PNG or anything that supports transparency.

---

Here's an example. Create a magenta input image:

```
magick -size 600x400 xc:magenta input.dds
```

[image]

Make a black-white gradient greyscale TIF:

```
magick -size 600x400 gradient: alpha.tif
```

[image]

Use greyscale gradient as alpha layer in magenta original:

```
magick input.dds alpha.tif -compose copyalpha -composite result.dds
```

[image]

---

If you are using v6, or older, of ImageMagick, replace all occurrences of `magick` in my command lines above with `convert`.

Comment: Thanx a lot Mark! imagemagick gave me what I  wanted exactly!